# PEX / CPVC leak-test

Tags: pex, cpvc

The leak check includes a visual self-inspection of each end of a pressurized new PEX pipe.  The PEX is to be piped into existing CPVC: the plan is to leak-check every 12 hours.  How many days should the leak-check be performed to provide a reasonable assurance that the joints / connects are good?

UPDATE

Followup inspection 12 hours after the initial self-inspection found a very small leak at the PEX endpoints.

Comment: I would think your local inspectors would be dictating that along with the manufacturer's suggestions.

Comment: Will the test involve connection/disconnection? will that causer a loss each time?

Comment: @SolarMike. No disconnections: circuit will be completed.

Comment: In my experience the inspector just looked it all over once, while pressurized. If everything is correctly installed and there are no leaks, he signs off the plumbing. He may ask to see the tools used, e.g. for copper he may look at your solder and flux to ensure non-lead and non-corrosive, he may ask to see a reaming/deburring tool, etc. I am not familiar with PEX install but if special tools or methods are required make sure they are at hand.